# Representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_n\mathbb{C}$, the kernel of $V \otimes V^*$ will be adjiont representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am reading the book: Representation theory a first course by Fulton & Harris.The book give some examples about representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_4\mathbb{C}$. (p178 & p221)

In the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_3\mathbb{C}$, V is standard representation on $\mathbb{C^3}$, $V^*\cong \wedge ^2V$. We can see the representation $V \otimes V^*$ is not irreducible by the following map：

\begin{align}
tr: V\otimes V^* &\to \mathbb{C} \\
v\ \otimes u^*   &\mapsto \langle v,u^*\rangle = u^*(v)
\end{align}
The kernel will be adjiont representation. We can identify $V \otimes V^*$ with Hom$(V, V)$, then the map will be trace of $M(3, \mathbb{C})$, and the kernel will be traceless matrices.

My question is how to see the map is a map of $\mathfrak{sl}_3\mathbb{C}$ module.

I found the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3579163, but I can not add comment because of my reputation.

Thank Callum's answer.

Some thinking after Callum's answer.
If we consider the map(for $\mathfrak{sl}_n\mathbb{C},V=\mathbb{C^n})$:
\begin{align}
\wedge:\quad \quad V\otimes \wedge^{n-1} V &\to \wedge^{n}V\cong\mathbb{C} \\
v_1\ \otimes v_2\wedge...\wedge v_n   &\mapsto v_1\wedge v_2\wedge...\wedge v_n
\end{align}
It seems the map commutes with the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_n\mathbb{C}$ obviously, because   $\mathfrak{sl}_n\mathbb{C}$(even  $\mathfrak{gl}_n\mathbb{C})$ commutes with symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$?

Comment: It seems that after your original question was answered, you added a somewhat different question at the end. I think if you want answers to that one, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg , for $\mathfrak{sl}_n\mathbb{C}$, $\wedge ^{n-1}V \cong V^*$. I just mention it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I think it's easier not to identify $V^* \cong\bigwedge^2 V$ here and instead just use the dual (aka contragredient) representation directly.
Specifically this is the representation $\rho^*:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{gl}(V^*)$ where $\rho^{*}(X)(f) := - f \circ \rho(X)$ for $\rho$ the representation on $V$.

So then the representation on the tensor product looks like
$$ v \otimes f \mapsto \rho(X)(v) \otimes f - v \otimes f \circ \rho(X) =[\rho(X),v \otimes f].$$

Hopefully, it is clear from here that this action preserves the kernel of $\operatorname{tr}$ (indeed has image there) and its kernel is precisely the span of the identity. From this, we can quickly see that $\operatorname{tr}$ identifies the span of the identity with the trivial representation.

Note that this argument does not depend on whatever $\mathfrak{g}$ is, nor on whichever representation $V$ we are considering so there is always a copy of the trivial representation in $V\otimes V^*$ for any such choices of $\mathfrak{g}$-representation $V$. Of course in our specific example we have found the adjoint representation as the other component.

Comment: Funny, I never thought about that: Not only is $tr(X.t) = X.tr(t)$ but indeed $tr(X.t) =0$ for all $X \in \mathfrak g$ and $t \in V \otimes V^*$. And that's saying the same here, because the codomain of $tr$ is the ground field with *trivial* $\mathfrak g$-action.